# Links de serviços populares como parte do contexto de uma pergunta

Tags: debate

Devemos aceitar perguntas cujo contexto possui partes essenciais em links externos, porém de serviços populares?

Exemplo:
[Extrato tipo bancário complexo MySql como resolver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86151/extrato-tipo-banc%C3%A1rio-complexo-mysql-como-resolver)

Nesse caso específico, os códigos estão no serviço sqlfiddle.com.

Por mais que tais serviços sejam populares e estáveis, podemos confiar que os links sempre estarão disponíveis?

Comment: [É uma boa idéia colocar o código no Pastebin ao invés de colocar o código na pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4255/91) pelo menos o op demonstrou esforço em fazer um exemplo [testavel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nesse caso ai é só pedir para ele editar a pergunta e colocar o código.

Comment: valeu! editei e fiz os avisos.